# Backbone best way to change method for object

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, inheritance, backbone.js

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    action: function() {
        console.log('action');
    },
});
```

Can i override method at initialization, like:

```
var my_special_view = new MyView({
    action: function() {
        console.log('new action');
    },
})
```

Comment: i have a custom class and i want to create instance but with different method

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own custom views and then extend that instead of [Bacbone.View](http://backbonejs.org/#View).

For example

```
var MySpecialView = MyView.extend({
    action: function() {
        console.log('new action');
    }
})

var my_special_view = new MySpecialView();
```

If you really just want to override a method for a specific instance without creating your own custom view, you can directly override the function on the instance. For example

```
var my_special_view = new MyView();
my_special_view.action = function () {
    console.log('new action');
};
```

Comment: there is no way to inherit method without extend ?

Comment: You can always override the method on the instance as well for example (`mySpecialView.action = function () {...})`, but that looks to be a messier approach.

Comment: @Arti Any particlaer reason you don't want to use extend?

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
var my_special_view = new MyView();
my_special_view.action = function() {
    console.log('new action');
};
```

It just creates an instance of your view then redefine its 'action' method. I think it's exactly what you want because it enables you to use this implementation of 'action' just once, so it is really a *special* view.
Plus, it is a javascript features so you can use this with any library/framework you use.

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.